# Consuming SOAP in angular 4

Tags: angular, web-services, soap, ionic-framework

I am trying to use a plugin: [Angular 2 Soap Client Service](https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap) for angular 4 (in ionic app), however I came across an error when I included the service:

> Runtime Error
>       (void 0) is not a function

```
Stack
TypeError: (void 0) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:144165:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:144400:96)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:90575:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.__moduleName (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:144155:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:18
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69:10
```

I am still quite new with Angular, but I believe this has something to do with the plugin not working for webpack.

What would be a possible solution for this error?

Comment: That package doesn't seem to have been updated for over a year. It still uses Angular2 release candidates. Also I found this https://github.com/autopulous/angular2-soap/issues/12. Seems like someone else has the same issue as you and that issue hasn't been addressed for over a month. May be you should find a different package?

Comment: Please do not use the angularjs tag on angular 2+ questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Rama I did notice the issue but have been unsuccessful in finding other ng plugins for Soap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890719/creating-a-soap-client-with-angular-2