# How to get value from using SOAP in angular2?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, soap, ionic3

```
this.soapService.post(this.Base_Url, 'User', data)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  }).catch(error => {
    alert("Error  :" + error);
  });
```

I got result by JSON object but I couldn't able to get particular value

For ex: JSON.stringify(result[0].user), I got the status undefined

Comment: if your using default http from @angular/http, then you need to to `result.json()` to get the json object.

Comment: I couldn't able to use JSON.stringify(result.json()). I got the error [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'.
any

Comment: post the response log please

Comment: {
  "user": "xxx",
  "mobile":"xxxxxx"
  
} I got the response from success result, but I couldn't able to get resullt[0].user

Comment: your response is not an array. try accessing using `result.json()['user']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890719/creating-a-soap-client-with-angular-2

Comment: SOAP doesnt return JSON...

Comment: I agree suraj but, if we use soapservice and soapclient means we can able to get JSON format

Comment: hmm.. if you are getting `{ "user": "xxx", "mobile":"xxxxxx" }` then you will get value as `result.user`

Comment: I got the error suraj. [ts] Property 'username' does not exist on type '{}'

Comment: @S.M.Priya do not confuse runtime errors and compile time errors. If you get that error, then use a type assertion `const result = <{username?: string}>result.json();`. Also, what does this have to do with Angular or Ionic or even TypeScript?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad with error we can able to run and compile, right?

Comment: Depends on the error. As long as what you have is syntactically valid, it will produce valid JavaScript and run. But you should just figure out what the type should be and declare it.

Comment: am using this.soapService.post(this.Base_Url, 'user', data)
      .then(result => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error  :" + error);
      });